# Looping in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.5

I m doing a quiz project where the number of questions and number of options for a questions are dynamic (taken from a service url).Maximum 5 options for a question(but may be decreased).I m displaying it in  sectioned UITableView where each question and its options are displayed in one section.I m taking the objects in one section in a NSMutableArray and looping the options each time .But Im getting only the last option.
I couldnot understand why is it so ?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *hlCellID=@"hlCellID";

    UITableViewCell* hlcell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];

    if(hlcell == nil)
    {
        hlcell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:hlCellID]autorelease];

        hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        lblQuestion = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        lblQuestion.tag = 1;
        lblQuestion.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblQuestion setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
        [lblQuestion setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [hlcell addSubview:lblQuestion];

        lblanswers = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        lblanswers.tag = 2;
        lblanswers.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblanswers setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
        [lblanswers setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [hlcell addSubview:lblanswers];

    }
    int section=indexPath.section;
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int n=[sectionItems count];

   hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    NSString *question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Question"]];
    CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size1 = [question sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    lblQuestion = (UILabel *)[hlcell viewWithTag:1];
    lblQuestion.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",question];
    [lblQuestion setNumberOfLines:0];
    lblQuestion.frame = CGRectMake(10,25, size1.width, size1.height);


    for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Description"]);
        NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sectionItems  objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Description"]];
        CGSize constraint2 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size2 = [answer sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint2 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lblanswers = (UILabel *)[hlcell viewWithTag:2];
        lblanswers.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",answer];
        [lblanswers setNumberOfLines:0];
        lblanswers.frame = CGRectMake(10,20*j, size2.width, size2.height);
        [hlcell.contentView addSubview:lblanswers];



    }

    return hlcell;

}
```

I couldn't understand how to set the frame for a lblanswers.

EDIT:

```
-(IBAction)checkboxClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)
                              [[sender superview] superview]];


    NSLog(@"The section  is %d",  indexPath.section);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int tagID=[sender tag];

    int divnum=0;
    if(tagID<100)
        divnum=10;
    else
        divnum=100;
    int section=[sender tag]/divnum;
    section-=1;
    int itemId=[sender tag]%divnum;

    if(itemId==selectedrowforCheckBox)
    {

        if(self.isChecked ==NO)
        {
            self.isChecked =YES;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            NSMutableDictionary *hk=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [hk setObject:xWrapped forKey:@"Ans"];
            [hk setObject:questionId forKey:@"QId"];
            [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:hk];





        }
       else
        {
            self.isChecked =NO;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            for (int i=0;i<[selectedOptionandQIdArray count];i++)
            {

                NSString *qid=[[selectedOptionandQIdArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"QId"];
                if(xWrapped==[[selectedOptionandQIdArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Ans"] && [questionId isEqualToString:qid])
                {

                    NSLog(@"nnd");
                    [selectedOptionandQIdArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];

                }




            }



        }

        selectedrowforCheckBox=itemId; 

    }
    else
    {

        if(self.isChecked ==NO)
        {
            self.isChecked =YES;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            NSMutableDictionary *hk=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [hk setObject:xWrapped forKey:@"Ans"];
            [hk setObject:questionId forKey:@"QId"];


            [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:hk];



        }
        else
        {
            self.isChecked =NO;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        }

        selectedrowforCheckBox=itemId;

    }





}
```

Comment: i cnt get wt u want >? please explain clearly, and how many section of your table ..and pu screen shot for more understanding for us :)

Comment: after question Im getting last option only displayed.not all the options are displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Break down the work in to two parts:

Before that create a dictionary in which each key is question and associated object is an array which contains all the answers.

- number of sections = [dictionary count]
- number of rows per section = [[dictionary valueForKey:[[dic allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] count]

  1. Questions - create a custom view with UITextView and return that as header for each section and you can adjust the height by calculating and returning height based on question.
  2. Answers - create a custom cell with UITextView and set the text based on section and row.

This strategy will not only simplify the code by given it a structure but also specify the detection of answers selected by user, as you can just store indexPath and check the section for question and row for answer selected by user.

U can download a sample code from here: http://www.saplogix.net/QA/sample.zip

Comment: ok I will implement it .Can u tell me how can I get labels height in heightforrowatindexpath for each section.because when I say return label.frame.size.height it is returning zero and I couldnot see the label.And how can I handle selection of an answer in a section?

Comment: You need to pull the text you will set and calculate it's size.

Comment: @Sindhia Were you able to do that or you need me to post some code for you.

Comment: I am able to do it.Thank u.But I have a doubt .I have placed checkboxes to the left of each option and there can be 2 to 5 checkboxes in  each UITableViewCell.Now I m unable to get how to handle checked or unchecked status.Because the checkbox is clickable second time I check it.I knew it how to do for 1 checkboxes.But there are many checkboxes and I couldn't find an example of it in google.Can u please post some code for it,if there are multiple checkboxes

Comment: @Sindhia ok i will post a code late but you have to let me know the data structure your are using to keep your questions and answers.

Comment: @Sindhia UITableView is for displaying the questions and there answers, what i am trying to know is how do you store them in memory.  Do you have model for each question and answer or do you use CoreData ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24421/discussion-between-saplogix-and-sindhia)

Comment: @Sindhia were you able to finish it?